# How to Correctly set CountDownTimer in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Please help, I have a countdowntimer within a method that I need to pause and resume.
I managed to pause the timer by using the .cancel() in the onPause however I cannot get it to restart properly. 
I have 2 scenarios: 
Scenario 1- It pauses but when restarting it seems to restart both countdown timers even if the initial timer was cancelled.

```
    public void playAgain (View view) {

        score = 0;
        numberOfQuestions = 0;
        timerTextView.setText("60s");
        pointsTextView.setText("0/0");
        resultTextView.setText("");
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        returnToMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        resultDisplayTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        countDownText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sumTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long timeRemain) {

                    millisInFuture = timeRemain;

                    countDownText.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemain / 1000 - 60));

                    if (timeRemain <= 61000) {

                        timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemain / 1000) + "s");
                        button0.setEnabled(true);
                        button1.setEnabled(true);
                        button2.setEnabled(true);
                        button3.setEnabled(true);
                        button0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        sumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        countDownText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                }


                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    timerTextView.setText("0s");



                    if (score > 0) {
                        percentage = score * 100 / numberOfQuestions;
                    } else {
                        percentage = 0;
                    }

                    button0.setEnabled(false);
                    button1.setEnabled(false);
                    button2.setEnabled(false);
                    button3.setEnabled(false);
                    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    returnToMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    resultDisplayTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    resultTextView.setText(" ");
    }
            }.start();

        generateQuestion();

    }


 @Override
    public void onPause() {

        countDownTimer.cancel();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
CountDownTimer countDownTimer1 = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long timeRemain) {

                millisInFuture = timeRemain;

                countDownText.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemain / 1000 - 60));

                if (timeRemain <= 61000) {

                    timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemain / 1000) + "s");
                    button0.setEnabled(true);
                    button1.setEnabled(true);
                    button2.setEnabled(true);
                    button3.setEnabled(true);
                    button0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    countDownText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                timerTextView.setText("0s");



                if (score > 0) {
                    percentage = score * 100 / numberOfQuestions;
                } else {
                    percentage = 0;
                }

                button0.setEnabled(false);
                button1.setEnabled(false);
                button2.setEnabled(false);
                button3.setEnabled(false);
                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                returnToMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                resultDisplayTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                resultTextView.setText(" ");
}
        }.start();
}
```

The second scenario just crashes the system:

```
    public void playAgain (View view) {

        score = 0;
        numberOfQuestions = 0;
        timerTextView.setText("60s");
        pointsTextView.setText("0/0");
        resultTextView.setText("");
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        returnToMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        resultDisplayTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        countDownText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sumTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long timeRemain) {

                    millisInFuture = timeRemain;

                    countDownText.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemain / 1000 - 60));

                    if (timeRemain <= 61000) {

                        timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemain / 1000) + "s");
                        button0.setEnabled(true);
                        button1.setEnabled(true);
                        button2.setEnabled(true);
                        button3.setEnabled(true);
                        button0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        sumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        countDownText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                }


                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    timerTextView.setText("0s");



                    if (score > 0) {
                        percentage = score * 100 / numberOfQuestions;
                    } else {
                        percentage = 0;
                    }

                    button0.setEnabled(false);
                    button1.setEnabled(false);
                    button2.setEnabled(false);
                    button3.setEnabled(false);
                    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    returnToMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    resultDisplayTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    resultTextView.setText(" ");
    }
            }.start();

        generateQuestion();

    }


 @Override
    public void onPause() {

        countDownTimer.cancel();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
countDownTimer.start();
}
```

I have googled and cannot seem to find a working solution.
Please help, Galaxy store refuses to upload my apk unless this feature works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, CountDownTimer is a relatively limited class. It only has two methods, `start()` and `cancel()`, and two callbacks, `onTick()` and `onFinish()`. There is no pause/resume functionality built in.

I set up a very basic Activity with a TextView to visualize the CountDownTimer's behavior, and it is working like you want - pausing when leaving activity, and resuming when you return. I've posted the simple code here:

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000L;
    private long timeRemaining = 60000L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeRemaining, INTERVAL) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                mTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d sec.", l / 1000L));
                timeRemaining = l;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTextView.setText("Done.");
            }
        };
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

I'd start with checking if you can get this code to run, and then integrate the basic idea into your project. You essentially have to maintain the time remaining outside of the CountDownTimer object.

Comment: Thanks it works however I am now experiencing a problem with the timeRemaining variable, it should reset to 60000 when playAgain is pressed. I have tried resetting it in the playAgain method but it is not working. I have reset it in the on resume but then it resumes on the 60sec mark instead of the time left. Everytime I now playAgain it starts from the timeRemain = l position.

Comment: I even tried creating a method calling the timeRemain

Comment: @HansFouche you could try to reset `timeRemaining` to 60000 in the `onFinish()` of the CountDownTimer?

Comment: Thanks I have tried that as well. It is so weird that the variable does not want to reset. I am suspecting it might be something to do with the onTick but cannot find any documentation on that.